# What is the meaning of "a branded soul"?

Tags: word-usage

I read a sentence in "The Hindu" which was:

> There is too much adventure and wonder meant in this world to sit by the sidelines, no matter how branded soul you may possess.

"Branded" generally means "carrying a brand name". But that doesn't seem to fit here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Branded** also means *"marked with a branding iron."*

Here, a Branded Soul might mean a sad soul, one that has gone through a lot of bad experiences and sufferings.

So, the sentence would mean, that no matter how sad or tortured one's soul is, there is always something exciting in the world for him to experience.

Answer (score -2):

I think in this context it would mean your soul is branded as the property of God.

Comment: Can you support this opinion?

Comment: Welcome to English Language Learners and thanks for your answer. This answer has been flagged by the system as a possible low quality answer because of its length and/or content. Just so you're aware, this community values answers that are well thought out and help the questioner learn and understand English better. How is 'branded' used in your answer and how is it understood in the question? Are they different? What about the context gives you clues to the meaning of the word? How can we understand that 'branded' actually does fit here? Those are the implied questions that need answering.